# Comparing base types in reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am calling a method on an assembly using reflection and I need to first compare if one of the parameters for the method has the same base type with the parameter I am passing in for it.

But whenever I call `passedInParameter.GetType().BaseType()` it returns "

> {Name =
>   "MarshalByRefObject" FullName =
>   "System.MarshalByRefObject"}.

Shouldn't it be showing the interface it is implementing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime has helpers for this:

```
if (typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(passedInParameter.GetType()))
{
}
```

---

Backgrounder:

Interfaces are *not* basetypes. CLR types cannot have multiple base types.

You should be able to enumerate interfaces implemented by a type, but as you can see from my proposed solution, I don't recommend doing all that

Comment: I've observed that "typeof(SomeType).IsAssignableFrom(param.GetType())" will return false when param is a TransparentProxy, while "param is SomeType" will return true.

Answer (score 2):

Interface is not a base class. Class may implement a lot of interfaces
If you want to get list of interfaces just use

```
passedInParameter.GetType().GetInterfaces();
```

also you can try to use [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) operator

```
if(passedInParameter is ISomeInterface)
{
    // do some logic
}
```

Try to use this code snippet

```
    ParameterInfo param = paramList[i]; 
    Type type = paramArray[i].GetType();

    bool valid = false;
    if (info.ParameterType.IsInterface)
        valid = type.GetInterfaces().Contains(param.ParameterType);
    else
        valid = type.IsSubclassOf(param.ParameterType);
```

Comment: You can pass concrete types into a method's parameter that is expecting an interface. What is that called? Passing by its implementation?

Comment: You just pass object that implements those Interface

Comment: @Stecya - right...that's what i said. I just thought that was called passing by its base type...Just asking what the term is for doing that.

Comment: You don't need to use typeof here

Comment: don't know whether there is special term for such passing

Comment: @username,digEmAll - yeah, my typo

Comment: paramArray[i].GetType() is param.ParameterType <- why won't this work?

Comment: ParameterInfo param = paramList[i]; <- where param comes from

Comment: @Gho5t because you cant you `is` in that way, its compile error.

Comment: Allthough all of this is nice and _enterprisey_, it is not robust and is about as effective as shooting a mosquito using a canon